# React Router Behaviour on Page Reload

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-redux

This is a bit weird and I would like to get to the bottom of it.

I have a Product Details page where I check if URL matches with a specific param then, it will continue otherwise it should replace with that specific parameter and reload the page.

It is working fine. But when I reload page with wrong params, condition fails and page reloads with new params. But the problem is, after reload, condition again fails (there is still last state params state in routes) and therefore it keeps reloading the page.

P.s. I'm checking condition in `ComponentWillMount` function.

Here is my code for further elaboration:

```
componentWillMount() {
    if (!matchParam(this.props.category, this.props.param) {
      this.props.dispatch(push(this.props.param));
      }
  }
```

Comment: Can you include some code snippets? It is difficult to debug based on a description.

Comment: @PaulS I just added code of componentWillMount Module. It keeps reloading the page if I write wrong URL and hit enters.

Comment: Is the URL changing when the page reloads?